# Postgres Error enlarging string buffer for binary smaller then 1GB

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4

I am running a python script to upload binary file content to a postgres table. However the process exits with the following error while handling a file of 0.812932GB or 793 MB:

```
psycopg2.errors.ProgramLimitExceeded: out of memory
DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by 1664884015 more bytes.
```

Which seems like its allocating a lot more than the filesize of the binary. Why is this?

Offending code:

```py
        with open(file_to_store["fqpn"], "rb") as binary:
            cursor.execute(
                sql.SQL(
                    "INSERT INTO {}.{} (filesystem_dir, filename, "
                    "file_bin) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                ).format(
                    sql.Identifier(self.table_schema),
                    sql.Identifier(self.table_name),
                ),
                (
                    file_to_store["directory"],
                    file_to_store["filename"],
                    binary.read(),
                ),
            )
            con.commit()
        con.close()
```

where `file_to_store["fqpn"]` is the fully qualified path to the 793MB file.

So the question is, why is there a buffer allocation for more memory than the file needs and how do I fix that?

Comment: Take a look at  using `psycopg2.Binary()` for providing the third parameter's value.

Comment: Perhaps it is converting the binary data into an escaped text format, which is at least twice as big. Don't store huge data like that in the database, you'll live to regret it.

Comment: Any way to convert input data to hex before inserting with psycopg2? It seems like postgres automatically accepts both hex and escaped, hex should be smaller/